Am I sanitizing the input properly in my functions.php?
I am creating a WordPress website, using Divi Builder for the design + some PHP for additional functionality in the back-end. Right now I am developing custom Divi modules, whose purpose will be to fetch data from my MongoDB database and display it, if everything works as expected. Here is the logic:
// ... create-divi-extension code
private function get_mongodb_data() {
    $uri = "...";

    $client = new Client($uri);

    $db = $client->selectDatabase("...");
    $collection = $db->selectCollection("...");

    $result = $collection->find();

    $data = [];
    foreach ($result as $document) {
        $data[] = $document;
    }

    return $data;
}

public function get_content($mongodb_data) {
    $content = '';

    foreach ($mongodb_data as $test) {
        $test_name = isset($test->test_name) ? $test->test_name : '';
        $points = isset($test->points) ? $test->points : '';
        $test_id = isset($test->_id) ? $test->_id : '';

        $test_page_url = esc_url( 'https://test.net/tests/' . $test_id );
        $content .= sprintf(
            '<div>
                <h1>%1$s</h1>
                <h4>%2$s</h4>
                <a class="go-to-test-btn" href="%3$s">%4$s</a>
            </div>',
            $test_name,
            $points,
            esc_url( $test_page_url ),
            esc_html__( 'read more', '...' )
        );

    }

    return $content;
}

I won't share the actual website, because it is not important for my question.
So the idea is whenever I click this button <a class="go-to-test-btn" href="%3$s">%4$s</a>, to be redirected to the particular test. Inside the functions.php file of my WordPress website, I implemented this logic to be executed, upon getting redirected to this URL ('https://test.net/tests/' . $test_id):
function check_mongodb_for_test($test_id) {
    try {
        $uri = "...";
        $client = new MongoDB\Client($uri);

        $db = $client->selectDatabase("...");
        $collection = $db->selectCollection("...");

        $objectID = new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId(strval($test_id));
        $result = $collection->findOne(['_id' => $objectID]);

        return $result !== null;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        error_log("Error occurred in check_mongodb_for_test: " . $e->getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'custom_template_redirect');

function custom_template_redirect() {
    $url_path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
    $url_parts = explode('/', trim($url_path, '/'));
    $test_id = end($url_parts);

    $test_exists = check_mongodb_for_test($test_id);

    if ($test_exists) {
        $redirect_url = add_query_arg('test_id', $test_id, get_permalink('1300'));
        wp_redirect($redirect_url);
        exit;
    }
}

function redirect_if_test_id_is_invalid() {
    if (is_page_template('test-custom-template.php')) {
        if (!isset($_GET['test_id'])) {
            wp_redirect(home_url('/all-tests'));
            exit;
        } else {
            if (!check_mongodb_for_test($_GET['test_id'])) {
                wp_redirect(home_url('/all-tests'));
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_if_test_id_is_invalid');

So I am getting the test_id, searching for document with such ID inside and redirecting to different URL (will solve the many redirections later on), while setting the ID as a query parameter, in order for other custom modules inside this page to be able to use it for fetching other data, if that document exists inside the database.
My question is if it is safe to do those operations like this. I am basically doing some sanitization before starting to query inside the database (inside the functions.php file), but my concern is that anyone can input anything inside the URL. So I am thinking if this is the proper way to go further. If it is not an optimal and safe way, please guide me on how to optimize and improve the security of this logic.
Here is an example module, that is used inside the page, to which the user gets redirected, if the retrieval from the database is valid:
<?php

require __DIR__ . '../../../../vendor/autoload.php';

use MongoDB\Client;
use MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId;

class TEYO_Instructions extends ET_Builder_Module
{

    public $slug = 'teyo_instructions';
    public $vb_support = 'on';

    protected $module_credits = array(
        'module_uri' => '',
        'author' => '...',
        'author_uri' => '',
    );

    public function init()
    {
        $this->name = esc_html__('Instructions', '...');
    }

    public function get_fields()
    {
        return array(...)
           
    }

    public function render($attrs, $content = null, $render_slug)
    {
        $instructions = $this->get_instructions();
        $content = $this->display_instructions($instructions);
        return $content;
    }

    private function get_instructions()
    {
        try {
            $uri = "...";

            $client = new Client($uri);

            $db = $client->selectDatabase("...");
            $collection = $db->selectCollection("...");

            $test_id = isset($_GET['test_id']) ? new ObjectId(strval($_GET['test_id'])) : '';

            if ($test_id) {
                $result = $collection->findOne(["_id" => $test_id]);
                if (!empty($result)) {
                    return $result->terms_of_service;
                } else {
                    throw new Exception('Invalid retrieval from the database!');
                }
            } else {
                throw new Exception('test_id seems to be invalid.');
            }
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            error_log($th->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function display_instructions($instructions)
    {
        if (empty($instructions)) {
            throw new Exception('There are no chapters passed!');
        }

        $content = sprintf(
            '<div style="margin: 16px;">
                    <h2><strong>Instructions</strong></h2>
                    <h3>%1$s</h3>
                </div>',
            $instructions
        );

        return $content;
    }

}

new TEYO_Instructions;


safe against what threat(s) exactly? Which bit of this code do you regard as the "sanitisation" bit? And how are you writing such code if you don't know what threat you're trying to protect against? It's like asking for a vaccination but not knowing what disease you want to be protected from.

Hey, @ADyson, well, for example if someone types in a MongoDB query inside the query param test_id, or for example injects some malicious script through them, it is called Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attack, if I am not being wrong. So they are the ones that are concerning me. Thank you! :)

@ADyson, regarding the sanitisation code -> the new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId, as much as I am aware, sanitizes against malicious input. Also the redirect_if_test_id_is_invalid is also working as some sort of protection against such inputs inside the query param test_id when the page loads.

Your redirect_if_test_id_is_invalid isn't doing anything about "malicious" code or data, it simply checks if the provided ID already exists in your database or not. That's business logic / validation, not security / sanitisation.  And the ObjectId constructor will simply validate that the string passed in (if any) is a 24-character hexadecimal string or not - again that's validation that it can work with the data meaningfully, and has nothing to do with security or threat protection as such.

my concern is that anyone can input anything inside the URL...they can, but as we've seen, if they do that then it will likely fail to create a valid ObjectId, and probably throw an exception, which should show up in your log (since you're catching exceptions in that block). Have you tested it at all?

if someone types in a MongoDB query inside the query param test_id, or for example injects some malicious script through them, it is called Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attack...for XSS not unless you somewhere output that provided param data into a web page, without HTML-encoding it first. Nothing in the PHP code you've provided is doing that. Please try to read up and understand how such problems actually occur. Simply passing data into an app is not a threat in itself - it's what an app does with it after that which can potentially cause issues.

Typing a mongo query in there wouldn't be XSS either - that term specifically refers to injecting JS code into web pages, to be executed by browsers. It might be considered a query injection attack, but could only really occur if you were to pass that input parameter raw to Mongo via a function which directly executes it as a mongo query. Again I don't see anywhere in the PHP code which is doing that. And, again - have you tested it or attempted such a thing, to see what happens?

Hey @ADyson, my bad about the XSS, sorry. I haven't tested with such mongodb query, was just asking if there is a way to do so. I have tested with wrong ID, or without query parameter and it redirects me to the given page. So from what you typed, I understood that there is no need to worry about such malicious inputs or queries, because they cannot happen in PHP? Sorry, I am quite new to PHP and am not really sure about how everything works in here. Thanks for your patience! :)

From what I can see of the mongodb PHP extension there doesn't seem to be a way to execute a raw query through it, and if there is your provided code certainly isn't using it.

Thank you, @ADyson! You answered my concerns and now I know it is safe to continue like that. Can I give you the answer to the question somehow, you deserve it!

And yeah your code sufficiently validates the input ID against the database to ensure it gets no further in this script if the ID doesn't exist. What I don't know is what happens if someone takes a valid $redirect_url value (as generated by $redirect_url = add_query_arg('test_id', $test_id, get_permalink('1300'));) when it shows in their browser and modifies the test_id parameter in that URL with something else, and requests that modified URL - presumably that URL executes some other code in your PHP, and presumably you haven't shown us that

@ADyson, If I understood you correctly, this is just WordPress function that constructs a URL. The get_permalink('1300') is getting the WordPress page ID, to which I want to redirect and the other part just adds the ID as a query parameter.

Yes I understand that. But the point is, presumably that page then also processes that test_id, using some different code than the code you've shown here? So therefore we have no idea if that page's script deals adequately with the ID data or not, in order to use it safely.

@ADyson, I don't have any other code, related to those processes, rather than the one, which is already shown here. :)

So then what does your $redirect_url redirect to then?? It must go somewhere? You say it redirects to a wordpress page, so presumably that page has some code which deals with the test_id and uses it for something? Does it use the same code you've already shown us? That wouldn't rally make sense, because presumably that would end up with infinite redirects. Therefore there must, logically, be some other code which processes that request.

@ADyson, actually the modules inside that page are doing some querying with this test_id, which is why I added that query parameter at first place. They are really similar to the module, that I have posted in the description, but I will also add one of those custom modules in the description. Just to clarify -> the page doesn't have any code, that uses that query string, only the modules inside it. P.S., I added one of the modules in the question description!  :)

Thanks for the update. No obvious XSS or query injection issues in that code either, I would say.

@ADyson, so everything should be safe, right? :)

As far as I am able to observe from the code you've shown, it should be safe against those two threats
